# Java XPath evaluation always null

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm working on this for days now and I have no idea why i can't get it working. I created some java code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder;
Document doc = null;
try {
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = builder.parse(xsl);

    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

    try {
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//xs:attribute-set[@name = \"tableImportantLine\"]/xs:attribute/text()");
        NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

which should read this xsl-fo file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
  <xs:attribute-set name="cell-style">
    <xs:attribute name="border-width">0.5pt</xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="border-style">solid</xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="border-color">black</xs:attribute>
  </xs:attribute-set>
  <xs:attribute-set name="block-style">
    <xs:attribute name="font-size">  10pt</xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="line-height">15pt</xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="start-indent">1mm</xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="end-indent">  1mm</xs:attribute>
  </xs:attribute-set>

  <xs:attribute-set name="thickText">
    <xs:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xs:attribute>
  </xs:attribute-set>

  <xs:attribute-set name="tableImportantLine">
    <xs:attribute name="background-color">#86f442</xs:attribute>
  </xs:attribute-set>


  <xs:attribute-set name="tableOutlineStyle">
    <xs:attribute name="border">solid 0.5mm black</xs:attribute>
  </xs:attribute-set>

  <xs:attribute-set name="tableStyle">
    <xs:attribute name="border">solid 0.1mm black</xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="text-align">center</xs:attribute>
  </xs:attribute-set>

  <xs:attribute-set name="tableHeaderStyle">
    <xs:attribute name="border">solid 0.1mm black</xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="text-align">center</xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xs:attribute>
  </xs:attribute-set>

  <xs:attribute-set name="stripedDesign">
    <xs:attribute name="background-color">#123FC2</xs:attribute>
  </xs:attribute-set>

</xs:stylesheet>
```

I removed the fo-templates because they are pretty big and compile without problems (apache-fop).
I've checked my XPath, it should work perfectly to get '#86f442'. Still, the XPath selector returns 0 nodes all the time and is null...
The document contains the xml though.
I am thankful for anyone whos helping.

//edit:
I also tried to directly select '//xs:attribute-set' instead of the more specific xpath selector. Still only returns an empty nodelist.
Same happens when I use

> String node = expr.evaluate(doc);

with

> //xs:attribute-set[@name =
>   \"tableImportantLine\"]/xs:attribute/text()

which returns null..

Comment: Make sure you use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext-javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext- to pass in a class implementing https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html with the bindings you need for your XPath expressions.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks, i haven't known that. This fixed my problem. Thank you so much.